# Set the same value to multiple properties (CSS)

Tags: css

Is there a way to set multiple CSS properties to one value?

```css
border-left, border-right: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
```

The way that you can do with selectors?

```css
.wrapper, .maindiv { ... }
```

Comment: No, but [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) variables can get you close.  Come to think of it, you should propose this for the next version of SASS.  Worst that can happen is that your idea gets rejected.

Comment: good call, I wrote to lesscss instead

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Nope. But for your example, you can do this:

```css
border: solid #E2E2E2;
border-width: 0 1px;
```

The attributes where there can be separate values for top, right, bottom, and left (eg, border-*, margin, padding) can usually be combined in a single attribute.

Comment: it seems that if you want to set only top and left you have the maximum number of bytes, as you have to specify 0 for right and bottom.

Answer (score 6):

Not possible, unless you do:

```css
border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
```

..which sets the same border on all sides. If you want to control them individually, you have to write them as separate statements.

Note that in some cases, you can set multiple values for one attribute, but you can not have multiple attributes with one value in one statement.

Answer (score 6):

Not possible with plain css, but you may have a look at [scss](http://sass-lang.com/) or [less](http://lesscss.org/) who might have solutions for your problem.

A solution with plain css is the following:

```css
border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
border-width: 0px 1px;
```

Comment: I've looked at sass before. It's not a huge problem, I was just curious :) thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using sass, try this:

```
@mixin border($properties , $value){
    @each $property in $properties{
        border-#{$property}: $value;
    }
}

selector{
    @include border(left right, 1px solid #E2E2E2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If the attributes are related, as is the case with `border-left` and `border-right`, there usually is a common attribute that allows you to set them:

```css
border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
```

On the other side, there are some libraries like [Less CSS](http://lesscss.org/) out there that extend CSS so that you can easily group related properties and attributes.

Answer (score 4):

CSS does not allow such control. A workaround is to use larger rule, then restrict it:

```css
border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
border-top: 0;
border-bottom: 0;
```

But you end up with more code. Another solution is to use CSS "compiler", like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](http://lesscss.org/)