# Shorthand to set height and width of an element in CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

Basic question but I can't find it anywhere, is it possible to set the width and the height on the same line at the same time with the same value in my CSS?

I'm not asking for something like:

```
width:100%;height:100%;
```

But more like one of those:

```
width, height: 100%; // Same for both
width, height: 100%, 90%; // Different for each ones
dimensions: 100% 90%; // Like padding/margin,
```

I'm just asking about declaration, not Javascript on how to do that.
[I found a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240130/set-the-same-value-to-multiple-properties-css) to this one but for border and the short answer was no.

If it's not possible with CSS, is it with SCSS ?

Comment: Some say that SCSS can do the trick but I did not found how in documentation...

Comment: It's still a valid question @musefan. I've thought about it before, how handy it could potentially be. Would be a bit redundant as it's only 1 extra line, but i'm lazy :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no short hand for setting the `height` and `width` of the element in a single property declaration. You cannot do it with SASS as well.

But yea, SASS will provide you a feature to hold the common value shared in both property by declaring a `variable` like

```
$some-var-name: 100px;

.some-class {
  height: $some-var-name;
  width: $some-var-name;
}
```

As I said, even SASS won't help you writing `height` and `width` at the same time but you can use change the value of both from a single variable.

---

Ok I was about to add the `@extend` in the answer but since other user has already answered the same, (*which is now deleted*)

```
.size{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

element {
    @extend .size;  //Sets element to height:100%;width:100%;
    // more stuff here
}
```

I would suggest you to use a declaration of `%` instead of `.` so instead of using `.size` suggested use `%size`. This way your literal class of `.size`  used only for extend purpose won't be included in the compiled stylesheet.

Comment: I've never heard of the `%size` way, so I +1'd as that sounds like it would be more useful! :)

Comment: If the other answer gets deleted, your final paragraph won't make much sense. Just put what you intended and forget about mentioning the other answer

Comment: @Albzi Thanks and yea its handy, I often use `%` because I don't want to print the extend collection class in my stylesheet

Comment: Thanks! I learnt something new! I'll use that in future thanks :) Like @musefan said you should write my answer in yours, it's more complete that way, then I can delete my answer :)

Comment: Woah @Albzi, bit extreme... there was no need to actually delete your answer.

Comment: @Albzi no idea why did you deleted your answer as it was also one of the valid way to do it

Comment: My answer was a bit redundant as Mr. Alien had written a better solution from my answer. I'm not too worried about the points. No point my answer getting more score as I was in front of him and I get the accepted answer when it should be his anyway :) @musefan

Comment: Your answer covers it much better :)

Comment: @Albzi Your answer also added valuable suggestion to the question but anyways I feel respected for you (not cuz you deleted your answer but you said *'m not too worried about the points.*)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that :) You taught me something I didn't know (regarding the `%`), so I'd say that's the point of coming here, learning, not earning points!

Answer (score 9):

you can use css variable

```css
/* css file */
:root {
  --length: 50px;
  --ratio: 1;
}
.box {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  width: calc(var(--ratio) * var(--length));
  height: var(--length);
}
```

```html
<!-- html file -->
<div class="box"></div>
```

then you can change `--length` in many ways and box width and height will respect to changes.
and Its better method than the SCSS variable for debugging purposes.

**Articles**
[Comparison between CSS variable vs SCSS variable](https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/)
[Why we prefer CSS Custom Properties to SASS variables](https://codyhouse.co/blog/post/css-custom-properties-vs-sass-variables)

Answer (score 8):

You can set up Sass Mixin, like this:

```
@mixin size($width, $height) {
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
}
```

Then write just:

```
@include size(100%, 100%);
```

Answer (score 5):

My little contribution if both w & h are equals :

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

This doesn't help much in typing, but with this, there is only one place to update.

Comment: Nice solution, I didn't know this

Comment: `aspect-ratio` Not supported by Internet Explorer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

To add onto the mixin solution by @Allrightman, you could even account for when the width and height are the same by setting a default value for the second parameter to equal the first:

```
@mixin size($width, $height: $width) {
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
}
```

If a user inputs a single value opposed to two, this will set them both to the same thing, covering both use cases.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to declare `height` and `width` at the same time in pure **CSS**, but you can use preprocessors css like **SASS** or **LESS** to declare the value to avoid repetition, but don't forget that after they get complied to CSS, they become pure CSS again...

Fo example in SASS you can do:

```
$width-height: 100%;

body {
  height: $width-height;
  width: $width-height;
}
```

So as you see, you can define it, but after it gets complied to CSS, it becomes like this again:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

But we all know this is not always the case, the CSS for the big applications could be much more complex, and reusing and declaring values using preprocessors css will help a lot to manage your css in a tidier way!...